# Кнопка на сенсорном экране

Tags: button

Мне понадобилось реализовать класс `Button` для сенсорного экрана. **(Не использовать готовое решение)** **(Вопрос не привязан к конкретной платформе, интересует лишь принцип)**

Являясь пользователем `Android`, я, конечно же, понимаю, что если просто отслеживать попадание `touchDown` по кнопке и активировать ее `onClick` по `touchUp` - не вариант. Пользователь может поставить палец на кнопку, потом передумать и сдвинуть его. Поднимет он его уже не в границах кнопки, а та все равно нажмется.

Можно дополнительно отслеживать, что `touchUp` был произведен тоже в границах кнопки. Но это все равно не очень удобно для пользователя, когда кнопка большая.

Тогда, немного порывшись в `libgdx`-реализации кнопки, я нашел нечто вроде `tap square`. Как я понял, это что-то вроде квадратика вокруг точки, куда пользователь нажал. Если он поднял палец в границах квадратика `&&` в границах кнопки, то клик проходит. Ну логично.

Проще всего отслеживать расстояние между точкой, в которой пользователь нажал на кнопку и точкой, в которой он поднял палец. Если это расстояние меньше, чем максимальное, то тогда вызываем `onClick`. Тогда как правильно настроить расстояние? И ведь его нужно настраивать не просто в пикселях, а с учетом `dpi`? Мой вариант меня вроде бы устраивает, но хотелось бы знать, так ли это обычно делается, или же я что-то упускаю?

Ссылочки приветствуются.

Comment: onClickListener не подходит?

Comment: @iamtihonov а при чем тут какой-то `onClickListener`? Вы вопрос-то прочитали? Я спрашиваю не то, как использовать что-то готовое на дроиде, а как это реализовано

Comment: Как это какой то, это стандартный механизм. То что он вам не подходит в вопросе вы не указали и возможно вы создаете велосипед, тем более что вы говорите какой-то, о простой пещи в Android. Вопрос я ваш прочитал. Более конкретно сформулируйте ваш вопрос и укажите его в заголовке.

Comment: `Мне понадобилось реализовать класс Button для сенсорного экрана`. Вы знаете, что такое "реализовать"? Мне нужно сделать кнопку для движка, я интересуюсь тем, как это сделано в разных фреймворках, к примеру, дефолная `Button` в андроид, или же `Button` в `libgdx`.

Comment: что, если посмотреть исходники класса View (от которого и наследуются все виджеты в Android). Android - система открытая и его исходники доступны в той же IDE, чтоб далеко не ходить

Comment: @pavlofff, угу, как раз этим сейчас и занимаюсь

Comment: "реализовать — осуществить, исполнить, выполнить, воплотить в жизнь, претворить в жизнь, привести в исполнение" - реализовать можно и стандартную обработку кнопки, которую предоставляет Android. Конкретнее нужно стараться формулировать вопрос и проще отвечать на вопросы в комментариях.